# Twilio - Need solution to log only selected WEBHOOK Requests in a twilio voice call when Request Inspector is disabled

Tags: twilio

In Twilio do we have option to log only specific WEBHOOK HTTP Requests for incoming voice call?

Do we have option to debug HTTP errors produced when Inspector is disabled?

Shall we access call log Http Request, Response status programmatically when Request Inspector is disabled ?

Please help me to get the solution for above questions.

Comment: These don't seem like programming questions, I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who will be able to help you.

Comment: Thank You. We also raised same query to Twilio Support but we haven't got any answer from them.

Comment: Can you email me at philnash@twilio.com with your ticket number and I'll try to chase that up.

Comment: Thank You for your support. I have sent an email sharing ticket details to philnash@twilio.com. Please follow up as soon as possible.